# Turn a table into a list of row/column/value tuples

Tags: google-sheets

I want to turn a table like this

```
|          | apple | banana | chia |
|----------+-------+--------+------|
| antelope | 1     | 4      | 2    |
| bear     | 6     | 3      | 9    |
| cheetah  | 8     | 2      | 1    |
```

into a table containing the same data, but with one row for each value, explicitly listing the row header, column header, and the value.

```
| antelope | apple  | 1 |
| antelope | banana | 4 |
| antelope | chia   | 2 |
| bear     | apple  | 6 |
| bear     | banana | 3 |
| bear     | chia   | 9 |
| cheetah  | apple  | 8 |
| cheetah  | banana | 2 |
| cheetah  | chia   | 1 |
```

Ideally, modifying the original table will automatically update the tuple table.

Comment: Perhaps this answer is of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40060/29140

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, for a 1-formula solution automatically updating when new rows are added, try:

```
=ArrayFormula({trim(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A2:A&char(9),counta(B1:1))), char(9)))), transpose(split(rept(join(char(9), B1:D1&char(9)),counta(A2:A)), char(9))), transpose(split(CONCATENATE(B2:D&char(9)), char(9)))})
```

NOTE: after adding a name in column A, column B, C and D can not be left blank.

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z_PyuZySe_qHDnSMPO50SRRZB1R4d_vv0vdScDTiqq0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: An alternative to the alternative: automatically updating when rows, columns or both are added   `=ArrayFormula({trim(transpose(split(concatenate(rept(A:A&char(9),counta(1:1))), char(9)))), transpose(split(rept(join(char(9), OFFSET($A$1,0,1,1,counta(1:1))&char(9)),counta($A$2:A)), char(9))), transpose(split(CONCATENATE(offset($A$1,1,1,counta(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))&char(9)), char(9)))})`

Comment: Improvement: In case of empty cells in the values range, the following formula returns "Empty" for each empty cell instead of an error: `=ArrayFormula({trim(transpose(split(concatenate(rept($A:$A&char(9),counta($1:$1))), char(9)))), transpose(split(rept(join(char(9), OFFSET($A$1,0,1,1,counta(1:1))&char(9)),counta($A$2:$A)), char(9))), transpose(split(substitute(char(9)&CONCATENATE(offset($A$1,1,1,counta($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1))&char(9)), char(9)&char(9),char(9)&"Empty"&char(9)),char(9)))})`

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in A1:D4

Add the following

Row labels (first column), F2:F10, use

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$2))/COUNTA($A:$A))+1,0)
```

Header labels (second column), G2:G10, use

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$2)+1,COUNTA($1:$1))=0,COUNTA($1:$1),MOD(ROW()-row($F$2)+1,COUNTA($1:$1))))
```

For the values (third column), H2:H10, use

```
=Index(OFFSET($A$1,1,1,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1)),Match($G2,OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)),0),MATCH($H2,OFFSET($A$1,0,1,1,COUNTA($1:$1)),0))
```

If a new rows or columns are added, just fill down until you get all the required tuples.

File that shows the above formulas working
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YCxCEVU_zO3NL8vi95B4adoHoPMc8fWZUK2mTLG6MQc/edit?usp=sharing