# Split varying number of columns of one row into multiple rows?

Tags: google-apps-script

Reading the related question [Split content of one row into multiple rows?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39822/45867) thought you might be able to steer me in the right direction.

I am working with data in Google Sheets that I would like to parse using a script or formula, similar to the solution you solved for.

In my case, I have URLs in Column A and a list of email addresses as variables associated with that URL in Column B, C, D, etc..
I would like to parse the sheet, so that the emails in B, C, D, etc. get added as new rows under column B, along with the matching URL from Column A.

Here is the process in action: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10PJR6738WyQmJTX3VFMEdIdnc/view

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere well out of the way I suggest something like:

```
=transpose(split(textjoin("|",1,B1:E1000),"|"))
```

then an INDEX/MATCH that relies on entries in that new column matching with entries in your existing B column to find the corresponding A values.

They may need copying down with something of the kind:

```
=if(isblank(A2),A1,A2)
```

See [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?visit_id=1-636409459168937508-3001294408&hl=en-GB&rd=2) for syntax.